# Form handling php script doesn't work properly

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I created an html signup form(signup.php).And I put `dbf/signup.dbf.php` as action page which is in `dbf` folder. Following code belongs to `signup.dbf.php`."dbc.dbf.php" is the script which provides the connection to database.

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['createbtn'])){
    require 'dbc.dbf.php';

    $uid=$_POST['uid'];
    $mail=$_POST['email'];
    $pwd=$_POST['pw'];
    $repwd=$_POST['re-pw'];
    $add=$_POST['address'];

    if(empty($uid)||empty($mail)||empty($pwd)||empty($add)||empty($repwd))
    {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emptyfields&uid=".$uid."&email=".$mail);
        exit();
    }

        else if(!filter_var($mail,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)&&!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]$/",$uid)){
        header("Location:../signup.php?error=invalidemailuid");
        exit();
    }   


    else if(!filter_var($mail,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)&&!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]$/",$uid)){
        header("Location:../signup.php?error=invalidemailuid");
        exit();
    }   

    else if(!filter_var($mail,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        header("Location:../signup.php?error=inavalidemail&uid=".$uid);
        exit();
    }

    else if(!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]$/",$uid)){
        header("Location:../signup.php?error=inavalideuid&email=".$mail);
        exit();
    }   

    else if($pwd!=$repwd){
        header("Location:../signup.php?error=passwordcheck&uid=".$uid."&email=".$mail);
        exit();
    }

    else{
        $sql="SELECT uid FROM user_details WHERE uid=?";
        $stmnt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmnt,$sql)){
            header("Location:../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
        exit();
        }
        else{

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmnt,"s",$uid);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmnt); 
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmnt);
            $results=mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmnt);
            if($results>0){
                header("Location:../signup.php?error=usertaken&email".$mail);
                exit();
            }
             else{
                 $sql="INSERT INTO user_details(uid,email,password,address) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
                     $stmnt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                 if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmnt,$sql)){
            header("Location:../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
                    exit();
                     }
                 else{
                     $hashpwd=password_hash($pwd,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmnt,"ssss",$uid,$mail,$hashpwd,$add);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmnt);
               header("Location:../index.php");
                    exit();
                 }
             }



        }

    }       

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmnt);
            mysqli_close($conn);


}

            else{
        header("Location:../signup.php");
             }
```

but when i click the `createbtn` of the sign up form it does neither save data in database nor redirect page to `signup.php`. It gets stuck always in `signup.dbf.php` displaying following code.

```
0){
                header("Location:../signup.php?error=usertaken&email".$mail);
                exit();
            }
             else{
                 $sql="INSERT INTO user_details(uid,email,password,address) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
                     $stmnt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                 if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmnt,$sql)){
            header("Location:../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
                    exit();
                     }
                 else{
                     $hashpwd=password_hash($pwd,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmnt,"ssss",$uid,$mail,$hashpwd,$add);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmnt);
               header("Location:../index.php");
                    exit();
                 }
             }



        }

    }       

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmnt);
            mysqli_close($conn);


}else{header("Location:../signup.php");
exit();}
```

Even if i commented this code it keeps displaying.**can anyone help me with this**?

Answer (score 0):

Are your PHP code being printed on the browser output?
Apparently this can just happen when you don't put the code inside the PHP tags properly. You're using the short PHP tag (`<?`) on your code which need the permission of `short_open_tag` on php.ini. Make sure this settings are set or use the default PHP tags.

Comment: yeah that worked!!!!actually i didn't active php.ini .after saw your answer i changed <? to <?php. then it worked...thank you so much.....